# Why do we need to have Object class as baseclass for all the classes?

Tags: c#, java, oop

Either in C# or Java or in any other language which follows oops concepts generally has 'Object' as super class for it by default. Why do we need to have Object as base class for all the classes we create?

When multiple inheritance is not possible in a language such as C# or Java how can we derive our class from another class when it is already derived from Object class. This question may look like silly but wanted to know some experts opinions on it.

Comment: So we don't need void pointers!!!

Comment: why deal with a forest if we can deal with a tree?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having a single-rooted type hierarchy can be handy in various ways. In particular, before generics came along, it was the only way that something like `ArrayList` would work. With generics, there's significantly less advantage to it - although it could still be useful in some situations, I suspect. EDIT: As an example, LINQ to XML's construction model is very "loose" in terms of being specified via `object`... but it works really well.

As for deriving from different classes - you derive *directly* from one class, but that will in turn derive *indirectly* from another one, and so on up to Object.

Note that the things which "all objects have in common" such as hash code, equality and monitors count as another design decision which I would question the wisdom of. Without a single rooted hierarchy these design decisions possibly wouldn't have been made the same way ;)

Comment: And for c# at least there is boxing - as everything derives from object, everything can be stored in an object. A bit better than void*

Comment: @simendsjo: That's mostly covered in my first paragraph, isn't it? That's why `ArrayList` was feasible. The question is, with generics, would you still need Object for this?

Comment: For heterogeneous collections, I suspect.

Comment: I came into the .Net game just recently, so I've never actually used an ArrayList :)

Comment: @Matthias: Hmm... possibly... I suspect there are various little corner cases like that. Can't say I use heterogeneous collections very often, but I'm sure they're handy sometimes :)

Answer (score 9):

The fact that every class inherits object ensured by the compiler.
Meaning that is you write:

```
class A {}
```

It will compile like:

```
class A : Object{}
```

But if you state:

```
class B : A {}
```

`Object` will be in the hierarchy of `B`  but not directly - so there is still no multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

In short

1) The Object class defines the basic state and behavior that all objects must have, such as the ability to compare oneself to another object, to convert to a string, to wait on a condition variable, to notify other objects that a condition variable has changed, and to return the object's class.

2) You can have B extend C, and A extend B.  A is the child class of B, and B is the child class of C.  Naturally, A is also a child class of C.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the multiple inheritance of `Object` does not apply - you can think of it as:

"If a type doesn't have a base type, then implicitly inject `Object`".

Thus, applying the rule ad-nauseam, all types inherit from object once and once only - since at the bottom of the hierarchy must be a type that has no base; and therefore which will implicitly inherit from `Object`.

As for why these languages/frameworks have this as a feature, I have a few reasons:

1) The clue's in the name 'Object Oriented'.  Everything is an object, therefore everything should have 'Object' (or equivalent) at it's core otherwise the design principle would be broken from the get-go.

2) Allows the framework to provide hooks for common operations that all types should/might need to support.  Such as hash-code generation, string output for debugging etc etc.

3) It means that you can avoid resorting to nasty type casts that can break stuff - like `(((int *)(void*))value)` - since you have a nice friendly supertype for everything

There's probably loads more than this - and in the time it's taken me to write this 6 new answers have been posted; so I'll leave it there and hope that better people than I can explain in more detail and perhaps better :)

Comment: 1) object oriented still works when not singly rooted. 2) the features could be provided by the language instead of a single root object of the library. 3) it might improve some designs _not_ to allow a "friendly super type for" _everything_

Comment: @nicerobot: 1) I never said that multiple inheritance violates OO. I said that a platform that pupports to be pure OO should have an Object supertype. Having more than one root supertype is entirely valid. 2) Of course they can be provided by the language - again I never said they couldn't (who cares where the functionality comes from?). In the case of .Net and Java, however, they *are* implemented by the supertype-which also means compilers have less work to do. 3) Perhaps so - but then you probably wouldn't have a pure OO environment?

Comment: @andras-zoltan I wasn't attacking you, but just elaborating on possibilities. As for "pure OO", i was just saying that it doesn't require a common supertype to still be pure OO and that doesn't imply supporting multiple inheritance. For example, in my root-less language, `class A{}` and `class B{}` don't have a common ancestor but the language can still enforce objects as the only types. I could, for example, implement `class Number{}` and `class Integer : Number{}` which have no hierarchical relationship to `class String{}` and i'm still a purely OO environment.

Comment: @nicerobot: i apologise for taking offence! :)  You've made your point elegantly there for sure - and I completely agree with you.

On a side note - I wish I could have multiple inheritance in C#. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of your question, it's how classes receive common properties and methods. It's also how we can have strongly-typed parameters to functions that can accept any object.

Regarding your second question, you simply derive your class from the other class; it will then be a descendant of that class, which is in turn a descendant of Object. There's no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You have the Object base class because amongst others because the Object class has methods (like, in .NET, `GetHashCode()`, which contain common functionality *every* object should have).

Multiple inheritance is indeed not possible, but it is possible to derive class A from class B, because A may not directly derive from Object, but B does, so all classes *ultimately* derive from Object, if you go far enough in the class' inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Just to compare, let's take a look at a language that doesn't enforce a single root class - Objective-C. In most Objective-C environments there will be three root classes available (`Object`, `NSObject` and `NSProxy`), and you can write your own root class by just not declaring a superclass. In fact `Object` is deprecated and only exists for legacy reasons, but it's informative to include it in this discussion. The language is duck typed, so you can declare a variable's type as "any old object" (written as `id`), then it doesn't even matter what root class it has.

OK, so we've got all of these base classes. In fact, even for the compiler and runtime libraries to be able to get anywhere they need some common behaviour: the root classes must all have a pointer ivar called `isa` that references a class definition structure. Without that pointer, the compiler doesn't know how to create an object structure, and the runtime library won't know how to find out what class an object is, what its instance variables are, what messages it responds to and so forth.

So even though Objective-C claims to have multiple root classes, in fact there's some behaviour that *all* objects must implement. So in all but name, there's really a common primitive superclass, albeit one with less API than `java.lang.Object`.

N.B. as it happens both `NSObject` and `NSProxy` do provide a rich API similar to `java.lang.Object`, via a protocol (like a Java interface). Most API that claims to deal with the `id` type (remember, that's the "any old object" type) will actually assume it responds to messages in the protocol. By the time you actually need to *use* an object, rather than just create it with a compiler, it turns out to be useful to fold all of this common behaviour like equality, hashing, string descriptions etc. into the root class.

Answer (score 1):

Well multiple inheritance is a totally different ball game.

An example of multiple inheritance:-

```
class Root
{
public abstract void Test();
}

class leftChild : Root
{
public override void Test()
{
}
}

class rightChild : Root
{
public override void Test()
{
}
}

class leafChild : rightChild, leftChild
{
}
```

The problem here being leafChild inherits Test of rightChild and leftChild. So a case of conflicting methods. This is called a diamond problem.

But when you use the object as super class the hierarchy goes like this:-

```
class Object
    {
        public abstract void hashcode();
        //other methods
     }

    class leftChild : Object
    {
    public override void hashcode()
    {
    }
    }

    class rightChild : Object
    {
    public override void hashcode()
    {
    }
    }
```

So here we derive both classes from Object but that's the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

It acts like a template for all the objects which will derive from it, so that some common functionality required by every object is provided by default. For example cloning, hashcode and object locking etc.